# How to reset the auto increment number/column in a MySql table

Tags: mysql, sql

The item_category_id column is auto increment value in the mysql table.

I need to delete all the values & next insertion should start from 1. If i delete all values & try to insert a new row then it starts with some 30's & 40's.

```
  item_category_id  item_category_name
    1                     qqq
    25                    ccc
    32                    vvv
    29                    bb
    4                     bbb
    31                    hhh
    34                    mmm
    33                    rrr
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Instead of using Delete if you use Truncate that will remove data and will also reset autoincrement.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE TABLENAME
```

Comment: Unless you have foreign keys, in which case, you need to add `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` before the truncate and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;` after

Answer (score 8):

If you're using PHPmyAdmin to manage your database, you could simply

- Select `YOUR_TABLE`
- Navigate to `More`
- Then, navigate to `Operations`
- There you will find an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field that you can alter:

[image: How to change <code>AUTO_INCREMENT</code> value]

Answer (score 5):

[Reset the auto increment value for a MySQL table](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/reset-auto-increment-value-mysql/)

```
ALTER TABLE `users` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SET  @num := 0;

UPDATE your_table SET id = @num := (@num+1);

ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

I think this will do it

Comment: I agree with your answer but I don't agree with the last alter statement. Say if you have 1000 records, your update statement will technically reset the id values to be from 1 to 1000. It doesn't make sense after that to set the AUTO_INCREMENT value back to 1, rather it should be 1001. Does that make sense?
The alter should be something like:
ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT = ((SELECT MAX(id) FROM your_table)+1);